# how to resolve unable to open amqp operation timeout issue in production?

Tags: node.js, azure-eventhub

Below is the eventhub producer code. The below issue is constantly occuring for my nodejs application since few days.
 `Unable to open amqp connection connectionid =21 due to operation timeout`

Producer.js

```
const { EventHubProducerClient } = require("@azure/event-hubs");

const connectionString = "EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING";
const eventHubName = "EVENT HUB NAME";

async function main() {

  // Create a producer client to send messages to the event hub.
  const producer = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName);

  // Prepare a batch of three events.
  const batch = await producer.createBatch();
  batch.tryAdd({ body: "First event" });
  batch.tryAdd({ body: "Second event" });
  batch.tryAdd({ body: "Third event" });    

  // Send the batch to the event hub.
  await producer.sendBatch(batch);

  // Close the producer client.
  await producer.close();

  console.log("A batch of three events have been sent to the event hub");
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log("Error occurred: ", err);
});
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies":{
"@azure/arm-eventhub":"3.3.0",
"@azure-eventhubs":"5.5.2",
"@azure/eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob":"1.0.1",
"@azure/identity":"1.4.0",
"@azure/storage-blob":"12.6.0",
"azure-arm-eventhub":"3.2.0"
}
```

NodeJs version is 10

Is there anyway to code a retry logic in case of these amqp failures?
Can anyone help me out in resolving the issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide an option to the  `EventHubProducerClient`.

The retry option would include `maxRetries` and `retryDelayInMs`

```
new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString: string, eventHubName: string, options?:{ "maxRetries": 4, "retryDelayInMs": 30000 })
```

Refer [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/event-hubs/eventhubproducerclient?view=azure-node-latest).